# WebApi integer validation

Tags: validation, asp.net-web-api

I'm using WebApi model validation to validate my request to only accept integer in the body by doing this:

```
[Range(0,10)]
public int AwesomeLevel { get; set; }
```

But if i send in a string value, the validation does not fail and the AwesomeLevel is set to 0.

```
AwesomeLevel="NotValid"
```

How can I make sure my validation will fail when a non integer value, in this case a string, is sent for this property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your model to be

```
[Required, Range(0, 10)]
public int? AwesomeLevel { get; set; }
```

This should force the client to set a valid value for the property. See [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) for more details.